# How long are piBase extensions going to be supported by TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, pibase

I tried to find the answer on the web, but there seems to be no information at what point old piBase extensions are going to stop working in TYPO3.

The transition of the "old" TYPO3 in direction of FLOW is visible, but I have to give a client an assessment of how long he will be able to use a piBase extension he had custom programmed.

With the current 6.2 LTS Version he should at least be save for the next two years, but does anybody know more about the plans regarding piBase?

Thnx

Florian

P.S.: My apologies if there is an article somewhere explaining this that I didn't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concluding this discussion http://typo3.3.n7.nabble.com/TYPO3-6-2-which-Extensions-will-still-work-td244691.html you don't need to afraid that will be dropped soon, anyway...

Keep in mind that next versions of TYPO3 rises PHP requirements, introduces depreciated and/or removed functions etc. Therefore if author of some extension won't fix it to fit new requirements it can stop working even tomorrow. That happened many times before and will happen in the future - for sure. Lot of extensions written let's say ten years ago doesn't work even in 4.x branch.

It's *rather* obvious, that if you/client want to continue with newest stable versions of TYPO3 you need to prepare to massive debugging of old fashioned extensions and also rewrite some part of them.

Finally if some TYPO3 instance works well on 4.x you don't need to rise it only because there's new polished 6.x in such case I'd recommend to leave it "as is" and develope new functionality with newer versions ***avoiding*** next piBase exts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to the discussion, that helps a lot. Thing is, at some point he will have to upgrade from 4.5 to 6.X (most likely 6.2) and the decision is rewriting everything in Extbase/Fluid or only update everything to get it running again. If piBase would have been dropped anytime soon, there kind of is no choice then rewriting his stuff. But again, thnx for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting custem extensions now, otherwise it may be required on some next T3 upgrades in deep future ;) Sometimes during such a large upgrade it's just better to start new portal on newest stable src and then just migrate data to new solution... but it's depending on many factors.

Comment: I would suggest that, too, but as always money is the issue here :).